# Как сделать, чтобы auto-fill заполнял только определённое количество места при масштабе 100%

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, веб-дизайн, css-grid

**Всем** доброго времени суток. Недавно начал учить html и css. Увидел как кто-то рекомендовал сайт с заданиями и решил пройти, а сейчас стараюсь как можно ближе повторить сайты, которые давали в конце изучения некоторых основ.

Проблема в том, что на сайте из примера, объекты при уменьшении масштаба начинают складываться в одну линию, хочу сделать также, но не получается.

*Вот скриншоты примера:*

[image: скриншот примера]
Скриншот на 100% масштабе.

[image: скриншот примера с уменьшенным масштабом]
И вот скриншот, когда масштаб уменьшается.

У меня получилось сделать так, чтобы они складывались, но при этом при 100% масштаба на экране не 2 блока, как в примере, а 4 :

[image: скриншот моего решения с обычным масштабом]
Мой результат.

Подскажите,как сделать чтобы при 100% масштабе они не были на пол-экрана и не сбивались в кучку из 4 штук.

Вот код, который я написал:

```css
.body-container {
  width: 99%;
  height: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(20px, 444px));
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto;
  grid-template-rows: auto;
}
```

```html
<body class="body-container">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="image-container">
      <img class="cont-image" src="image.jpg">
      <p>Tribute Page</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: У вас в коде только один элемент внутри контейнера. Заполните, его пожалуйста, элементами. Можно просто с фиксированной шириной и каким-то цветом чтобы не возиться с картинками.